# Is this circuit a Sallen & Key biquad?

Tags: filter, sallen-key

So I came up with the following filter to analyze:

[image]

My first thought was that this reminded me of a Sallen & Key biquadratic section. However I'm having trouble identifying each component. Taking the general Sallen & Key structure:

[image]

Let's start with the obvious ones:

$$Y_3=sC_3$$

$$Y_4=sC_2$$

$$Y_5=\frac{1}{R_4}$$

Now comes the troublesome part.

I would guess that
$$Y_1=\frac{1}{R_1}$$

And we can make Y2=0? What about the R5+R6 series resistors (assuming ideal OpAmp)? How do I fit them here to work with the equations?

Comment: This is not Sallen-Key filter but multiple feedback filter https://www.analog.com/media/ru/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-220.pdf

Comment: One key aspect of the Sallen Key is positive feedback

Comment: I rather would say.....Sallen-Key filters have finite gain (can be positive or negative).

Comment: The shown circuit is a 2nd-order allpass in "multiple-feedback" topology.